# node.js clearTimeout() not working

Tags: node.js, cleartimeout

I try to build an alert function which fires after 5 Min if my garagedoor is still open. The problem ist that no matter what message comes after "offen" the cleartimeout is not working, so the Alert is executed after every "offen"status. would be great if someone can give me a hint...

```
    function handleGarageState(message) {
      Status = message.toString();
      garageState = message
      io.emit('Garagenstatus', {
        data: String(garageState)
      });
      var Eintrag = {
        Datum: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        Status: Status
      };
      writeStatus(Eintrag);
      if (Status == 'offen') {
       var alert = setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("ALERT "); //here will be the alert function
        }, 60000 * 5)
      } else {
        clearTimeout(alert);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please show more of your code. from where do you call handleGarageState? In which scope do you define alert?

Comment: just add another clearTimeout before setTimeout. Something like if(alert){clearTimeout(alert); }

Comment: I tried to define the variabel alert within the if statement (edited it right now) and also as global variable ( var alert = "";)

Comment: Now, that you've modified the example, you define alert in the scope of handleGarageState, which means, it will be always undefined when you give it to clearTimeout as a parameter.

Comment: hmm makes sense,so defining it within the if statement is defenitly wrong. I alread tried it with a global variable - same issue...

Comment: @volker, in `ES5` you can not define a variable inside of an `if` statement. Even if you do it, it'll be defined in the beginning of actual functions scope. Read more about variable hoisting here: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

Comment: @Adam thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function handleGarageState(message) {
    Status = message.toString();
    garageState = message;
    io.emit('Garagenstatus', {
        data: String(garageState)
    });
    var Eintrag = {
        Datum: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        Status: Status
    };
    writeStatus(Eintrag);
    if (Status == 'offen') {
        //v-- Here
        var alert = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("ALERT "); //here will be the alert function
        }, 60000 * 5)
    } else {
        clearTimeout(alert);
    }
}
```

You are creating a new var `alert` on each call to that function. Problem is, the old `alert` is still waiting somewhere.
You need to centralize `alert` outside the scope of the function **and** clear it before putting a new timeout.

```
var alert;

function handleGarageState(message) {
    Status = message.toString();
    garageState = message;
    io.emit('Garagenstatus', {
        data: String(garageState)
    });
    var Eintrag = {
        Datum: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
        Status: Status
    };
    writeStatus(Eintrag);
    if (Status == 'offen') {
        clearTimeout(alert);
        alert = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("ALERT "); //here will be the alert function
        }, 60000 * 5)
    } else {
        clearTimeout(alert);
    }
}
```

Comment: just tested it and it worked!! Thank you.  The combination of defining the variable outside **and** adding the additional clearTimeout was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do'nt see where you defined alert, so maybe you got offen multiple times and you don't clear old timeouts and you overwrite the alert value and only clear the last timeout.

Answer (score 0):

For "react": "^17.0.2", "react-dom": "^17.0.2",

**To be noted:** This is a function.

I faced the same problem, As per now, I can only solve it by using **state**

I'm using **setTimeout** and **clearTimeout** in navbar, here is my full code,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Navbar = (props) => {

    // https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#navigate-function
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [state, setPosts] = useState({ alert: null });

    const setRainbow = (e) => {
        if (e.target.text === 'About') {
            clearTimeout(state.alert)
            var a = setTimeout(() => {
                navigate("/contact");
            }, 2000);
            setPosts(s => ({ ...s, alert: a }));
        } else {
            clearTimeout(state.alert)
            setPosts(s => ({ ...s, alert: null }));
        }
    }

    return (
        <nav className="nav-wrapper red darken-3">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to="/" className="brand-logo">Poke'Times</Link>
                <ul className="right" onClick={setRainbow}>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

This includes useState, Link, NavLink, useNavigate